# Compiler not understanding my optional argument in Python

Tags: python

Hello I'm having issues with an exercise that is asking me to write code that contains a function, 3 dictionaries, and an optional argument.

**Here is my code:**

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_title, num_tracks):

    """Return artist and album title name."""
    CD1 = {'sonic': artist_name, 'his world': album_title}
    CD2 = {'shadow': artist_name, 'all hail shadow': album_title}
    CD3 = {'silver': artist_name, 'dream of an absolution': album_title}
    if num_tracks:
        CD = artist_name + ' ' + album_title + ' ' + num_tracks
    else:
        CD = artist_name + ' ' + album_title
    return CD.title()

disc = make_album('sonic', 'his world', '15')
print(disc)

disc = make_album('shadow', 'all hail shadow')
print(disc)

disc = make_album('silver', 'dream of an absolution')
print(disc)
```

Whenever I try to run my code however, my compiler states that it is missing 1 required positional argument: 'num_tracks' for my second print statement.

But this should not be an issue because of my if-else statement, unless I wrote my code incorrectly and the compiler isn't reading my if-else statement? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `def` the function with a [default for the argument to be optional](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values), e.g.:

```
# num_tracks=None means if not provided, num_tracks is set to None
def make_album(artist_name, album_title, num_tracks=None):
    ...
    if num_tracks is not None:
        CD = artist_name + ' ' + album_title + ' ' + num_tracks
    else:
        CD = artist_name + ' ' + album_title
```

Arguments without a default are always required.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a default to my optional argument. When I run my code, I'm not getting a syntax error anymore, however, '15' still shows up in my second and third printing statement even though I didn't include it in my second and third printing functions and I set my if-else statements to make num_track optional. Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: @PhantomDiclonius: Did you set the default as `num_tracks="15"` the way the (now deleted) other answer did? That would cause it. Make it `num_tracks=None` (the standard sentinel for "not provided/not set"), and make the test check for `num_tracks is not None`, so it's used only when a real value is given.

Comment: Yes at first I had num_tracks='15', then I set it to None like you said and it worked, thank you. :)